# This piece of code gives me an error, and I can't figure out why?

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the biggest number in that struct array with this code:

```
max=0;
for (i = 1; i <= team.Length; i++)
{
    if (team[i].Point > team[max].Point) 
    { 
        max = i; 
    }
```

It gives me an error that it `System.OutOfRangeException`. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C# are 0-based, not 1-based.  Change your `for` loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < team.Length; i++)
```

**NOTE**: Edited based on feedback by @juharr

Comment: Actually since the OP initializes max to 0 it would work with `for (i = 1; i < team.Length; i++)`  It's just the `<` instead of `<=` that fixes it.